# How to achieve equidistant dashing in Plot

Tags: plotting

Even when plotting a seemingly simple function, Mathematica seems to screw up the dashing. If we take for instance

`Plot[Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full,  PlotStyle -> Dashed]`,

the resulting plot has uneven dashing around 2:

[image: Plot with uneven spacing]

When dragging a corner of the plot, it becomes apparent that the plotted line consists of two segments. As the segments are dashed individually, it does not line up at the point where the segments meet.

[image: Gif of plot behaviour when dragging a corner]

A workaround that I found is to manually evaluate the function on a mesh and doing a ListLinePlot of the results:

`ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}], PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Dashed]`

[image: Plot with workaround]

This seems a bit awkward, however, as it is the way `Dashed` should have behaved in the first place. So my question is: Is there any elegant way to stop Mathematica from separating the plot into segments and consequently screwing with the dashing?

Comment: I don't see this on v12.2.0-Win7-x86. What is your `$Version`?

Comment: My version is: 12.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)

Comment: This is reproducible with v13.1 on a Mac OS X x86. Changing the value of `PlotPoints` affects the number of "seams" and their locations. However you would need to experiment with values for `PlotPoints` for each `ImageSize`.

Comment: It seem my "workaround" does exactly that, changing `PlotPoints` to a value suitable for the plot size I chose. Using `{x, 0, 10, 0.01}`, I can reproduce the problem again.

Comment: Can not see this on Windows 10 MMA version 13.1

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

This doesn't actually stop the splitting of the plot-line into two parts, but it is an easier way to find a dashing that works and doesn't have the weird redrawing effect on resize.

For PlotStyle, use Dashing instead of Dashed:

```
Plot[Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Dashing[.03]]
```

[image]

However, compare to this:

```
Plot[Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Dashing[.02]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to use `MeshShading`. Unfortunately, you have to transform the geometry so that distance is isotropic:

```
{aratio, pr} = {AspectRatio, PlotRange} /.
   AbsoluteOptions[
    Plot[Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)], {x, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> Full], {AspectRatio, PlotRange}];
pratio = 1/Ratios[Differences /@ pr][[1, 1]];
Plot[Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, None}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> 100, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {pratio*aratio # &, 
   #/(pratio*aratio) &}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", "Standard"], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", "Nice"] @@ Last@pr}]
```

[image]